# Block url if it contains this query string using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to block or redirect the user if the user opens the url directly and if the url contains a query string.
I am doing this because I have a bot spam problem the bots automatically add things to wishlist

`https://example.com/xx/abc/?add_to_wishlist=15292`

The 15292 is the id of the product you cant hard code it so this should be the logic I am looking for:
If the url contains ?add_to_wishlist then block or redirect the user.

There are 2 things to this since the user opens the url directly https://example.com/xx/abc/?add_to_wishlist=15292

`RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} add_to_wishlist [NC] RewriteRule ^ - [F]`

Comment: Should work fine (assuming you did not actually write this all on one line), so what is the issue? Where did you put the .htaccess file? Is this all you got in there?

Comment: If you block all requests using this query string parameter, then why don't you simply ignore that parameter in your application logic?